# Unit Testing Vue 3 Component that uses Pinia with Vue Testing Library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia, vue-testing-library

I am struggling to understand how I can test the rendering of items based on the results of a call to a Pina getter in my Vue 3 app (using the Vue Testing Library). An example of what I want to achieve might be something like:

```
<div v-for="contact in store.getContacts()">
      <p>{{contact.firstName}} {{ contact.lastName }}</p>
</div>
```

where I want to test that all the names of the contacts are displayed.

My app uses Vitest and @testing-library/vue so in my test spec for the above test I might have:

```
import { cleanup, getByRole, render, screen } from "@testing-library/vue";
import { describe, it, vi, beforeEach, afterEach } from "vitest";
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";
import { createTestingPinia } from "@pinia/testing";

describe("MyComponent.vue", () => {

  let getByText: any, getByRole: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ({ getByText } = render(MyComponent, {
      global: {
        plugins: [
          createTestingPinia({
            initialState: {
              contacts: [{firstName:"Bill",lastName:"Jones"},{firstName:"Peter",lastName:"Smith"}],
            },
            stubActions: false,
            createSpy: vi.fn,
          }),
        ],
      },
    }));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });
  
  it("should display the first name", () => {
    getByText("Bill Jones");
  });

});
```

in the store I have the following state setup:

```
interface Student {
  "id": number;
  "firstName": string;
  "lastName": string;
  "house": string;
  "year": number;
  "class": string;
}

interface ContactState {
  contacts: Student[];
}

export const useContactStore = defineStore({
  id: "contact",
  state: ():ContactState => ({
    contacts: [],
}),
```

and a getter:

```
getContacts: (state) => {
      return state.contacts;
}
```

I think I have setup the initial state of the store correctly (??) but the getter does not seem to be working - what else do I need to do here? Do I have to mock the getter or something? Or maybe I am not initialising the store correctly in the test?

(my app is all working fine, it's the test I cannot get to work)

Comment: Could you clarify one thing and maybe show some code, what does your `store` look like?

Comment: I have made some edits above to show my store setup - thanks for looking in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the initial state using `createTestingPinia`, you also need to state the store `id`, also called `name`, which is in your case would be `contact` as seen in in your `defineStore`.

So in this case, I think what you should do is change the current code to this:

```
...
createTestingPinia({
    initialState: {
        contact: {
            contacts: [{firstName:"Bill",lastName:"Jones"},{firstName:"Peter",lastName:"Smith"}]
        },
     },
     stubActions: false,
     createSpy: vi.fn,
}),
...
```

This is not very well explained in the documentation, however, this should at least initialize the `contacts` array for you.